# Using SIGUSR1 and SIGUSR2 as signals in pthread_kill()

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

I would like to use SIGUSR1 and SIGUSR2 as arguments to pthread_kill() to suspend the execution of the running thread(i.e thread sends signal to itself) and resuming a suspended thread by a peer thread when a condition is met.
  Would be gratefull for any pointers like example code or views about it.

Thanks

Comment: You almost certainly want to use a mutex and condition variable for this instead of signals...

Comment: Homework ? If yes please tag accordingly.

Comment: Indeed, signals are absolutely wrong for this purpose.

Comment: @ Heandel..No it is not homework

Comment: @Nemo...Thanks..I will now use mutex and condition variable but just wanted to survey my options. Came across portions of the code of suspending and resuming threads with the above stated signals in the book "Programming with POSIX threads" and wanted views from more experienced programmers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I agree with Nemo, there are some valid use cases for suspending threads via signals.  The `susp.c` code in PWPT is certainly a good base but you can also find it used in [GLIBC](http://cs262-pthread.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/trunk/glibc-2.7/nptl/perf.c).  You might also wish to break the thread out of a blocking-IO system call (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203754/how-to-join-a-thread-that-is-hanging-on-blocking-io)) or interrupt a semaphore wait (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141289/how-do-i-terminate-a-thread-that-is-waiting-for-a-semaphore-operation)).

Comment: All of those examples have race conditions by their nature.  (That is,  you might send the signal _before_ the target thread manages to enter the blocking system call.)  Such race conditions are literally impossible to fix with 100% certainty, because there is always a window between a thread saying "I am going to block now" and when it actually enters the blocking call.  Just Don't Do It.  (Exception: sigsuspend(), which atomically changes the signal mask and waits.  Still, it's better to rewrite your code to use proper threading primitives.)

Comment: @Nemo - As I said at the start: I agree with you.  You should almost always use a mutex/condition variable.  But I think you should be careful with absolutes.  There are valid use cases for pthread_kill().

Comment: I agree there are always exceptions (hence the use of "almost certainly" in my comment), but in this case, I think they are more rare than even most skilled programmers realize.  Case in point: Your examples :-).

Answer (score 2):

Signalling is used as the following example. However, in your case though, you need Condition variables
https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#ConVarSignal has an example

```
 pthread_cond_wait (condition,mutex)
 pthread_cond_signal (condition)
 pthread_cond_broadcast (condition)
```

Example with the correct usage of the signals with **pthread_kill()** is demonstrated below

```
 /* ptsig.c
   This program illustrates the use of signals in threads.

   Three threads including the main thread.
   main thread
     a. Set up a signal mask to block all signals.
     b. Set up signal handlers for SIGINT and SIGUSR1.
     c. Create thread_1, detached.
     d. Create thread_2, nondetached.
     e. Send SIGINT & SIGUSR1 to thread_1.
     f. Quit.

   thread_1
     a. Unblock all to embrace all signals.
     b. Wait for signals.
     c. Send SIGINT and SIGUSR1 to thread_2
     d. Wait for thread_2 to terminate
     e. Print thread_2 return status.
     f. Quit

   thread_2
     a. Unblock SIGUSR1 -- all others blocked due to inheritance.
     b. Wait for signals.
     c. Quit

   Note: There is hardly any error checking in this example -- not a good
   idea, but to make the program a bit more easier to explain.

   To compile:  gcc  ptsig.c -lpthread 
                                                   Sam Hsu (11/19/10)
*/

#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 199506L
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

pthread_t tid2;
static void int_handler(int signo), usr1_handler(int signo);

void millisleep(int milliseconds)
{
      usleep(milliseconds * 1000);
}

main()
{
   pthread_t tid1;
   pthread_attr_t attr_obj;             /* a thread attribute variable */
   void *thread_1(void *), *thread_2(void *);
   sigset_t sigmask;                 
   struct sigaction action;

   /* set up signal mask to block all in main thread */
   sigfillset(&sigmask);                /* to turn on all bits */
   pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &sigmask, (sigset_t *)0);

   /* set up signal handlers for SIGINT & SIGUSR1 */
   action.sa_flags = 0;
   action.sa_handler = int_handler;
   sigaction(SIGINT, &action, (struct sigaction *)0);
   action.sa_handler = usr1_handler;
   sigaction(SIGUSR1, &action, (struct sigaction *)0);

   pthread_attr_init(&attr_obj);        /* init it to default */
   pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr_obj, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);
   pthread_create(&tid1, &attr_obj, thread_1, (void *)NULL);
   printf("TID(%u) created\n", (unsigned int)tid1);

   pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr_obj, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);
   pthread_create(&tid2, &attr_obj, thread_2, (void *)NULL);
   printf("TID(%u) created\n", (unsigned int)tid2);
   millisleep(1000);     /* for some reason a sleep is needed here */

   printf("main(%u) sending SIGINT to TID(%u)\n", (unsigned int)pthread_self(), (unsigned int)tid1);
   pthread_kill(tid1, SIGINT);          /* not blocked by tid1 */
   printf("main(%u) sending SIGUSR1 to TID(%u)\n", (unsigned int)pthread_self(), (unsigned int)tid1);
   pthread_kill(tid1, SIGUSR1);         /* not blocked by tid1 */

   printf("main(%u) is terminating\n", (unsigned int)pthread_self());
   pthread_exit((void *)NULL);          /* will not terminate process */
}  /* main */

void *thread_1(void *dummy)
{                               
   int sig, status, *status_ptr = &status;
   sigset_t sigmask;

   sigfillset(&sigmask);                /* will unblock all signals */  
   pthread_sigmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &sigmask, (sigset_t *)0);
   sigwait(&sigmask, &sig);
   switch(sig) {
     case SIGINT:
         int_handler(sig);
         break;
     default:   
         break;
   }
   printf("TID(%u) sending SIGINT to %u\n", (unsigned int)pthread_self(), (unsigned int)tid2);
   pthread_kill(tid2, SIGINT);          /* blocked by tid2 */
   printf("TID(%u) sending SIGUSR1 to %u\n", (unsigned int)pthread_self(), (unsigned int)tid2);
   pthread_kill(tid2, SIGUSR1);         /* not blocked by tid2 */

   pthread_join(tid2, (void **)status_ptr);
   printf("TID(%u) exit status = %d\n", (unsigned int)tid2, status);  

   printf("TID(%u) is terminating\n", (unsigned int)pthread_self());
   pthread_exit((void *)NULL);          /* calling thread will terminate */
}  /* thread_1 */

void *thread_2(void *dummy)
{                               
   int sig;
   sigset_t sigmask;

   sigemptyset(&sigmask);               /* to zero out all bits */
   sigaddset(&sigmask, SIGUSR1);        /* to unblock SIGUSR1 */  
   pthread_sigmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &sigmask, (sigset_t *)0);
   sigwait(&sigmask, &sig);
   switch(sig) {
     case SIGUSR1: 
         usr1_handler(sig);
         break;
     default:     
         break;
   }
   printf("TID(%u) is terminating\n", (unsigned int)pthread_self());
   pthread_exit((void *)NULL);          /* calling thread will terminate */
}  /* thread_2 */

static void int_handler(int dummy)
{
   printf("SIGINT received by TID(%u)\n", (unsigned int)pthread_self());
}  /* int_handler */

static void usr1_handler(int dummy)
{
   printf("SIGUSR1 received by TID(%u)\n", (unsigned int)pthread_self());
}  /* usr1_handler */
```

**pthread_cancel() is safer relative to pthread_kill()**

An example of **pthread_cancel()** below

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define handle_error_en(en, msg) \
       do { errno = en; perror(msg); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); } while (0)

static void *
thread_func(void *ignored_argument)
{
    int s;
    s = pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE, NULL);
    if (s != 0)
        handle_error_en(s, "pthread_setcancelstate");

    while (1) {
        printf("sleeping\n");

        sleep(1);        /* Should get canceled while we sleep */

    }

    /* sleep() is a cancellation point */


    /* Should never get here */

    printf("thread_func(): not canceled!\n");
    return NULL;
}

int
main(void)
{
    pthread_t thr;
    void *res;
    int s;

    /* Start a thread and then send it a cancellation request */

    s = pthread_create(&thr, NULL, &thread_func, NULL);
    if (s != 0)
        handle_error_en(s, "pthread_create");

    sleep(10);           /* Give thread a chance to get started */

    printf("main(): sending cancellation request\n");
    s = pthread_cancel(thr);
    if (s != 0)
        handle_error_en(s, "pthread_cancel");

    /* Join with thread to see what its exit status was */

    s = pthread_join(thr, &res);
    if (s != 0)
        handle_error_en(s, "pthread_join");

    if (res == PTHREAD_CANCELED)
        printf("main(): thread was canceled\n");
    else
        printf("main(): thread wasn't canceled (shouldn't happen!)\n");
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```